# Bash - find consecutive pipes in a file and remove the extra one

Tags: regex, bash, shell, solaris

I have one txt file with pipe as delimiter. I want to remove an extra pipe when there are 9 consecutive pipes whilst they should be 8 only.
I'm using an infantile script to do so. Just want to make it more professional with the use of regex to replace those repeated pipes.

Script:

```
sed 's/|||||||||*/||||||||/g' file_1.txt > file_1_new.txt
```

Comment: You say using regexps makes code look more professional?  I think one should use the most appropriate tool, which is then actually professional IMHO.

Comment: I can't understand your reasoning here: "Just want to make it more professional with the use of regex". You are already using a regular expression, BTW. What makes a code professional is its correctness, simplicity, and efficiency. Your expression could be incorrect in a way that it replaces 8 bars and zero or more consequent bars after the 8-th bar with 8 bars, if this is not what you want to achieve. You should clarify your question.

Comment: Here just a sample to clarify my question:                                                   
2019-10-22 22:48:20|customer_number|1111||Product||||||||Paris|33
2019-10-22 22:48:20|customer_number|2222||Customer||||||||Dakar|687
2019-10-22 22:48:20|customer_number|1111||Product|||||||||Paris|33
2019-10-22 22:48:20|customer_number|2222||Customer|||||||||Dakar|687  the last two lines have 9 consecutive pipes. In order to get the extra to be removed , the answer below is the perfect script. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming one line of your file looks like this,

```
a||||||||b||||||||e
```

then you can replace this by,

```
 sed 's/\(|\{8\}\)|/\1/g' file_1.txt > file1_new.txt
```

or even:

```
sed -ibak 's/\(|\{8\}\)|/\1/g' file_1.txt
```

Comment: It may not be available on Solaris, but with GNU sed on Linux you can use `sed -r` to get rid of most of the backslashes.

Comment: I think `sed -r` is same as `sed -E` in GNU sed. I remember the latter easily as it means `extended`.

Comment: The first option the best. Thank you